# <hr> element causing scrollbar, displacing elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project and the layout was working perfectly until I added hr elements. Doing so causes everything to shift and produces a vertical scroll bar to compensate. The horizontal rule is mandatory for my project.

I have borders enabled for my own clarity, but you can disable them at the top of the CSS. If you take out the hr's you can see how my layout should be.

```css
/* Explicitly make body element be full screen height*/
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

/* Cards */
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: black;
}

/* Paragraphs (snack card text) */
p {
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    height: 0.05rem;
    background-color: black;
}
/* Borders */
.container-fluid {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: orange;
}
.row {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thick;  
    border-color: red;
}
.col, .col-9, .col-3 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: purple;   
} 

/* Primary container */
#container-main {   
    background-color: rgb(230, 222, 220);  
    height: 100%;
}

/* Title Row */
#row-title {
    min-height: 10%;
}

/* Title Column */
#col-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Body row */
#row-body {
    min-height: 90%;
}

/* Snack rows */
#row-snacks-top, #row-snacks-mid, #row-snacks-bot {
    min-height: 33.333%;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

/* Snack columns */
#col-snack-1, #col-snack-2, #col-snack-3, #col-snack-4, #col-snack-5, #col-snack-6, #col-snack-7, #col-snack-8, #col-snack-9 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Inputs parent rows */
#row-money-parent, #row-messages-parent, #row-change-parent {
    min-height: 30%;
}

/* Money input rows */
#row-money-title, #row-money-input, #row-money-buttons1, #row-money-buttons2 {
    min-height: 25%;    
}

/* Messages display rows */
#row-messages-title, #row-messages-display, #row-messages-itemid, #row-messages-buybutton {
    min-height: 25%;
}

/* Change display rows */
#row-change-title, #row-change-display {
    min-height: 33.333%;
}

#row-change-return {
    min-height: 25%;
    max-height: 33%
}

/* Form display parent div */
.form-group {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Form display money */
#displaymoney {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    
}

#btn-add-dollar, #btn-add-dime, #btn-add-quarter, #btn-add-nickel {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: thick;
}

.btn-group {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

#displaymessages {
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#displayitemid {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#btn-buy {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 66%;
    border-radius: thick;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#displaychange {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#btn-change-return {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: thick;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Relearning Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Primary container -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-main">
        <!-- Title row -->
        <div class="row" id="row-title">
            <!-- Title column -->
            <div class="col" id="col-title"><h1>Vending Machine</h1></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- Body row -->
        <div class="row" id="row-body">
            <!-- Snacks column -->
            <div class="col-9" id="col-snacks">
                <!-- Top snacks row -->
                <div class="row" id="row-snacks-top">
                    <!-- Snack 1 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-1">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-1">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">1</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 2 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-2">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">2</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 3 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-3">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-3">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">3</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div> 
                <div class="row" id="row-snacks-mid">
                    <!-- Snack 4 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-4">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">4</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 5 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-5">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-5">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">5</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 6 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-6">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">6</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row-snacks-bot">
                    <!-- Snack 7 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-7">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-7">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">7</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 8 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-8">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-8">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">8</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Snack 9 column -->
                    <div class="col m-4" id="col-snack-9">
                        <div class="card" id="card-snack-9">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title">9</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Snack Name</p>
                                <p class="card-text">$0.00</p>
                                <p class="card-text">Quantity left: 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>               
            </div>
            <!-- Interface column -->
            <div class="col-3" id="col-interface">
                <!-- Money column -->
                <div class="row" id="row-money-parent">
                    <div class="col" id="col-money-parent">
                        <div class="row" id="row-money-title"><div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="col-money-title"><h3>Total $ In</h3></div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-money-input"><div class="col" id="col-money-input">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displaymoney" placeholder="$0.00" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-money-buttons1"><div class="col" id="col-money-buttons1">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-add-dollar">Add Dollar</button>
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-add-quarter">Add Quarter</button>
                            </div>                           
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-money-buttons2"><div class="col" id="col-money-buttons2">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-add-dime">Add Dime</button>
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-add-nickel">Add Nickel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <!-- Message column -->
                <div class="row" id="row-messages-parent">
                    <div class="col" id="col-messages-parent">
                        <div class="row" id="row-messages-title"><div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="col-messages-title"><h3>Messages</h3></div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-messages-display"><div class="col" id="col-messages-display">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displaymessages" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-messages-itemid"><div class="col" id="col-messages-itemid">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="displayitemid" class="inline-label">Item:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displayitemid" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-messages-buybutton"><div class="col" id="col-messages-buybutton">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-buy">Make Purchase</button>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <!-- Change column -->
                <div class="row" id="row-change-parent">
                    <div class="col" id="col-change-parent">
                        <div class="row" id="row-change-title"><div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="col-change-title"><h3>Change</h3></div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-change-display"><div class="col" id="col-change-display">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="displaychange" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                        <div class="row" id="row-change-return"><div class="col" id="col-change-return">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id="btn-change-return">Change Return</button>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I thought including the hr within my container would prevent this issue but apparently not. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: If you need the post gone, you can try flagging it. Editing doesn't work because we can still track revision history.

Answer (score 1):

try
hr{ max-width:100%}
or
body{overflow-x:hidden}

Comment: Overflow: hidden works, appreciate that. However from what I've found online this is somewhat hiding the problem. Would you know the real way of solving it? I will use this method until I find a better one thanks